# How to sort array with multiple criteria including the value of enum, names and numbers?

Tags: swift, xcode, sorting

I want to sort this array that i have named lists, which includs Player with Positions, what i want to achive is if the one value of Player is nill, for example either "position" in PLayer or year,, then it should be the last element of the array, and enum values according descending order and sort it

example: when i print the first element of array, it should print like names: "Teddy", "Joh", "Alex", "Sia", "Adix", "Javi", "Moris", "Yosa", "Leo", "Davi", "Cars".?

can someone help me to build the sorted func works as I want?

Here is my enum are the just priorities.

```
enum Position {
  case goalKeeper
  case defender
  case midfield
  case forward 
}
```

this is my Player struct

```
struct Player {
  var name: String
  var backNumber: Int?
  var position: Position?
}
```

and this is my list of players

```
let list = [
  Player(name: "Abbie", backNumber: nil, position: .defender),
  Player(name: "Tom", backNumber: 99, position: .goalKeeper),
  Player(name: "Carlos", backNumber: 88, position: nil),
  Player(name: "Javier", backNumber: 32, position: .midfield),
  Player(name: "Adam", backNumber: 32, position: .midfield),
  Player(name: "Luis", backNumber: 16, position: .forward),
  Player(name: "John", backNumber: 4, position: .defender),
  Player(name: "Morike", backNumber: 10, position: .forward),
  Player(name: "Silva", backNumber: 24, position: .midfield),
  Player(name: "Yoshida", backNumber: 10, position: .forward),
  Player(name: "David", backNumber: 8, position: nil)
]
```

and I want to sort it according the positions of the players in descending order
expected output will be like

```
print("\n\(["Tom", "John", "Abbie", "Silva", "Adam", "Javier", "Morike", "Yoshida", "Luis", "David", "Carlos"])")
```

this output above is supposed to achive using sorted method and depending on the positions of the players in descending order, Tom is goalkeeper so in the array it will be the first element, John is midfield ....... Morika and Yoshida is forward and so on,

Comment: Post code as text, not as an image. Images are not searchable and can't be copied into a text editor. Also add expected output for your example so it is clear what you want to achieve

Comment: Made changes, if you can please have a look,

Comment: What if there are two player with no position, what's the criteria then to put one before the other?

Comment: Yeah, if two players have nill position, first come first served. it will be added at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest solution is update the model where you will add new variable & have calculation for this variable.

```
struct Player {
  var name: String
  var backNumber: Int?
  var position: Position?

  var sortingVariable : Int? {
      get {
          if (position == nil || backNumber == nil || (name ?? "").isEmpty) {
              return 99 // let's say max limit is 99
          }

          if (position == goalkeeper) {
              return 1
          }
          if (position == defender) {
              return 2
          } // .... & so on...

          return 999 // dummy for nothing...
      }
  }

}
```

Now sort the array based on `sortingVariable`

```
var sortedArray = yourArrayList.sorted({ $0.sortingVariable > $1.sortingVariable })
```

This way, you can update logic at one place and can be used at any place for sorting.

Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort your array using the following code

```
let sorted = list.sorted {
    let firstPositionValue = $0.position?.rawValue ?? Int.max
    let secondPositionValue = $1.position?.rawValue ?? Int.max


    if firstPositionValue == secondPositionValue { // sort by back number or name
        let firstBackNumber = $0.backNumber ?? Int.max
        let secondBackNumber = $1.backNumber ?? Int.max

        if firstBackNumber == secondBackNumber { // sort by name
            return $0.name < $1.name
        }

        return firstBackNumber < secondBackNumber // sort by back number
    }

    return firstPositionValue < secondPositionValue // // sort by position
}
```

but to be able to sort by the enum the items needs to have a value, the following change will assign each item an increasing int value starting at 1

```
enum Position: Int {
  case goalKeeper = 1
  case defender
  case midfield
  case forward
}
```

If you want to you can assign the sort code to a variable

```
let sortFunction: (Player, Player) -> Bool = {
    let firstPositionValue = $0.position?.rawValue ?? Int.max
    let secondPositionValue = $1.position?.rawValue ?? Int.max
    //... code omitted for brevity 
    let sorted = list.sorted(by: sortFunction)
}
```

and use it like this to perhaps make the code more readable

```
let sorted = list.sorted(by: sortFunction)
```

Yet another option is to make the `Player` type itself sortable, to do this the type needs to conform to the [Comparable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/comparable) protocol

```
struct Player: Comparable {
    static func < (lhs: Player, rhs: Player) -> Bool {
        let firstPositionValue = lhs.position?.rawValue ?? Int.max
        let secondPositionValue = rhs.position?.rawValue ?? Int.max


        if firstPositionValue == secondPositionValue { // sort by back number or name
            let firstBackNumber = lhs.backNumber ?? Int.max
            let secondBackNumber = rhs.backNumber ?? Int.max

            if firstBackNumber == secondBackNumber { // sort by name
                return lhs.name < rhs.name
            }

            return firstBackNumber < secondBackNumber // sort by back number
        }
        return firstPositionValue < secondPositionValue
    }
    //... rest of code
}
```

then we can sort the array in an even simpler way

```
let sorted = list.sorted()
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but it says Position doest have a rawValue?

Comment: You didn't change the enum

Comment: if i change the enum, it is giving me another error though

Comment: What and where exactly "other error", please be more specific.

Comment: Without telling me what the error is I can't really help you. If you don't want to change the enum like this you can instead add a computed variable that returns a value for each item using a `switch` statement

Comment: it worked, I change the enum type to Int, but the thing is i cannot understand how it is working, I think i don't understand the sorted function and its return type. Would it be ok if you explain it in some detail?

Comment: The sort function has the same declaration as is required by the [sorted(by:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2296815-sorted) function so that is why it can be passed to `list.sorted(by:)`

Comment: @Ulugbek Any feedback on this?

Comment: I meant that I did not understand how actually sorted function works because i was using for loop inside sorted(), I mean the flow of instructions behind the scene of sorted()?